# How can I run a 12 volt car clock on C or D batteries?

Tags: clock

I have an old vehicle that I use a battery shut-off on so the clock doesn't tell the correct time.

I would like to figure out how to run it on alkaline batteries instead.

I have no idea how to do that.

update for clarity...i shut off the battery powered when i leave the truck.
Thank you very much to those who offered suggestions...I'm already working on them!!

Comment: I'd run it from a separate fuse, upstream of the battery shutoff. Unless it's a 1970s LED clock. Colleague built one out of TTL in about 1980. He took the bus into work the next Monday.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: :D

Comment: Do you want to *just* run it on alkaline batteries, or do you want to run it on alkalines when the battery is disconnected, and the car battery otherwise?  Do you have an idea of its current consumption?

Comment: you would connect 8 C or D batteries in series, the + of one into the - of the other.  Envision 8 batteries in a line.  Each is 1.5v, x 8 = 12.0 v.  Duracell does have a 12v alkaline battery, model 21/23, at about $6.  Or a 12v lantern type battery for $12 about the size of a can of soda.

Comment: Not sure if you could find a battery holder for the 21/23 style, like you easily would for a AA size.

Comment: amazon $6: LanLan 5Pcs 23A/A23 Battery (12V) Clip Holder Box Case Black.  With this you can complete your *The Hurt Locker* wiring job :)

Comment: A couple of rectifier diodes could be used to ensure that neither battery can (dis)charge the other, but both are able to supply current to the clock.

Comment: You should measure the current drawn by the clock to determine what size cells to use (AA, C, D, etc). Take milliampere-hour rating of the individual cells (ignore the fact they're in series, since this does not increase the capacity), and divide by the number of milliamperes drawn by the clock. That will tell you how many hours it will run before you have to change the batteries. IMHO, a better solution is to leave the main battery connected and add a battery maintainer.  Without this, the main battery - even disconnected - will discharge itself if you don't drive regularly.